# how to pass arraylist from jsp to javascript or jquery

Tags: jsp, struts1

I have an array list in ActionForm.

`Arraylist` - employee info like name,num,group etc.

Also i have 1 button in Jsp (Struts1.3):

If I click that button, a popup should display employee info in a `datagrid`.

**Suggestion Required:**

1. How to pass arraylist from jsp to javascript / jquery
2. How to design popup window in jsp (struts1.3)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a property with arrayList in your actionFrom,you could use logic:iterate to pass this arrayList to Javascript array.

```
var array = [];

<logic:iterate name="actionForm" property="arrayList" id="item">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var item = '<bean:write name="item"/>';
             array.push(item);
        </script>
</logic:iterate>
```

Then you can use jquery to populate them into a drop-down.